# Initialize Swift storyboard from Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, storyboard

I'm trying to add a new storyboard in Swift to an old Objective-C app:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard01" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OnboardingViewController"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

With Swift storyboard:

[image: Onboarding Storyboard]

I'm always getting error:

> 'Could not find a storyboard named 'MainStoryboard01' in bundle NSBundle <.../Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/753636C1-ABB5-4D6E-B184-5C4638FB2CE9/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/398410C0-BB2C-4574-B058-95D30F8D1B5D/Credit Call.app> (loaded)'

Calling swift classes like
    TestClass *instance = [TestClass new];
    [instance testFunction];

Normally works. Any idea how to call swift storyboard + it's swfit controller in Objective-C app?

// EDIT:

I finally get working this:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Onboarding" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainStoryboard01"];
```

but on next line

```
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

I get this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyAppDelegate presentViewController:animated:completion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6080000b3b60'

Any ideas? I need to replace this with the storyboard:

```
Registration *reg = [[Registration alloc] init];
registrationNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:reg];
[reg release];
[self.mainBackgroundView addSubview:[registrationNav view]];
```

=> https://codepaste.net/jkfras I've added skeleton of the MyAppDelegate.m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making mistake here, `MainStoryboard01` that you have set is `Storyboard Identifer` using that you can called `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`. It is not the another storyboard name. So its should be simply like this.

[image]

```
//You need to put storyboard name here the check the image for more detail
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [sb  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainStoryboard01"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**Edit:** Try this way.

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [sb  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainStoryboard01"];
[self.mainBackgroundView addSubview:[vc view]];
```

Comment: I'm not initializing it from an existing storyboard, but right from initializing app. It's made just with calling controllers and there is no storyboard in the app yet. Could you help me how to initialize as the first one? @nirav-d thank you a lot!!

Comment: @David Have you checked edited answer, Is it working now?

Comment: I'm just checking it and I'm getting this error:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CallBackAppDelegate presentViewController:animated:completion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6080000b3b60'
Thank you a lot for your care:)

Comment: @David Can you edit your question with your current try, also have you set proper storyboard name with `storyboardWithName`?

Comment: added below // EDIT:

Comment: @David From the error it is saying that you are presenting viewController from the appdelegate and that is not possible.

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm so confused how to deal with it, here is the skeleton of the MyAppDelegate.m file => https://codepaste.net/jkfras I'm taking the project from my predecessor

Comment: @David Are you adding this storyboard code in `initializeMainView` method of appdelegate?

Comment: @David Check my edited answer, May be you want something like that.

Comment: please I need to use jus UiViewController, than just change UINavigationController to UIViewController?

Comment: @David You want  `OnboardingViewController` as first View Controller when you launch the app?

Comment: I want to keep `UIViewController *controllerX = [[UIViewController alloc] init];` as rootViewController and this OnboardingViewController as the first subview , without any UINavigationController design stuff

Comment: Yes, that works, but if I use subview, it's not allowing to navigate between controllers on storyboard right? When i use `[self.window setRootViewController:vc];` instead of 
        `[self.mainBackgroundView addSubview:[vc view]];` then I can navigate between controllers

Comment: @David Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reference to a storyboard then you should use its name, so if your storyboard has a name "MyNewStoryboard" (MyNewStoryboard.storyboard) then the right way to create its reference is like this:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyNewStoryboard" bundle:nil];
```

Don't use a storyboard ID here. Storyboard ID you just set in the controller's attributes is the identifier for your controller. So you can use it this way:

```
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainStoryboard01"];
```

Change your new controller's Storyboard ID to something more informative, so for example "OnboardingViewController", and then after putting your storyboard file name in your first line your code should be fine.